# Can you use a member of deleter to keep alive a shared_ptr?

Tags: c++, shared-ptr, value-type

Given the following types

```
// interface and implementation used in one part of the codebase
struct Image
{
    virtual std::vector<uint8_t>& GetData () = 0;
};

struct VecImage : public Image
{
    std::vector<uint8_t> mData;

    std::vector<uint8_t>& GetData () { return mData; }
};

// used in another part of the codebase
struct PtrImage
{
    std::shared_ptr<uint8_t> mData;

    PtrImage (std::shared_ptr<Image> pIm);
};
```

is the following constructor a sane and correct way to convert an `Image` to a `PtrImage`?

```
PtrImage::PtrImage (std::shared_ptr<Image> pIm)
{
    struct im_deleter
    {
        std::shared_ptr<Image> keepAlive;
        void operator () (uint8_t* ptr)
        {
            keepAlive.reset ();
        }
    };

    mData = { &pIm->GetData()[0], im_deleter { pIm } };
}
```

`PtrImage` is used as a "value type", it is being passed around by value, while `Image` is passed around in shared_ptrs only.

Comment: As comments in answers evolve, I get more and more the impression that we are discussing an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). What are you *actually* trying to solve with this construct?

Comment: There are two "Image" types around the codebase and I'm trying to figure out whether one can be safely converted to the other without a copy. (instead of rewriting lots of code to use only one Image type everywhere.)

Comment: How would you represent actual image data in your system? I mean: if you have e. g. JPEG data, would you decode it? If you have a common internal image representation, then I'd rather write a loader and a storer class for each image type, each would load the data and convert it to internal representation (e. g. one RGB or RGBA set per pixel), and you finally would only handle one image type internally. The storer would just do the inverse. Image conversion then might look like: `LoaderJPG l; Image i = l.load("path to file"); StorerPNG s; s.store(i, "path to file");`

Comment: If you want to draw an image to screen or want to convert, you need some common denominator for all image types anyway... Of course, above sample could be done with smart pointers, too, if that's more appropriate; I personally would rather use the smart pointers *inside* the image class and pass the images themselves as either (const) references or perhaps in some specific cases by value. If you opt for smart pointers: let the loader return `std::unique_ptr` – it's more efficient to move a unique pointer into a shared one than having the shared overhead when you don't need it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks pretty dangerous to me:

```
std::shared_ptr<Image> i = std::make_shared<VecImage>(/* some data */);
PtrImage p(i); // has now stored a pointer to the vector's data
i->getData()->push_back(0); // repeat until re-allocation occurs!
```

What would p *now* hold? The shared pointer holds a pointer to the data that resided in the vector before re-allocation; but this data was replaced and got deleted. So you now have a dangling pointer stored in p (in the `uint8_t` pointer), using it (which will happen at latest when your smart pointer tries to delete its data) will result in undefined behaviour.

Answer (score 3):

> is the following constructor a sane..

You extend lifetime of `Image` thanks to destructor, so `data` is still valid.
So you are correct on that point...

**But**, vector may reallocate, invalidating the buffer.

So resulting code is unsafe.

You could store `std::shared_ptr<std::vector<uint8_t>> mData;` to be safe.

> .. and correct way

We have better/simpler with **aliasing constructor** of `std::shared_ptr`:

```
struct PtrImage
{
    std::shared_ptr<std::vector<uint8_t>> mData;

    PtrImage (std::shared_ptr<Image> pIm) : mData(pIm, &pIm->GetData()) {}
};
```

So ownership information `PtrImage::mData` is shared with `pIm`.

Note: *I assumes that vector returned by `GetData()` has same (or longer) lifetime that `Image` (as for `VecImage`). if it is an unrelated vector (from other object), then you won't have solution.*

As noted in comment, vector should not reallocate neither

Comment: From [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/shared_ptr): *'However, calling get() on this shared_ptr will always return a copy of ptr. It is the responsibility of the programmer to make sure that this ptr remains valid as long as this shared_ptr exists'* – if I read this right, we are only safe if no reallocations in the vector occur?

Comment: And the implementation in the question should suffer from the same problem, doesn't it?

Comment: @Aconcagua: Indeed, storing the vector would be safe though. answer fixed to handle that point.

Comment: Not entirely, though: in a multi-threaded scenario one thread might be iterating over the vector when another one invalidates the iterators by some means (e. g. by removing an element or provoking a re-allocation). If the intention was to get around such issues, well, still failed...

Comment: I know. But OP might have been aware of, too, and tried to preserve the original data this way. Why otherwise such a construct?

Comment: Oh, and I think you shouldn't use the aliasing constructor any more when storing the entire vector, otherwise nothing solved...

Comment: Hm, XY-problem (see question)?

Comment: Simply storing `std::shared_ptr<Image>` seems simpler, indeed.

Answer (score 0):

You should not even try to have a shared pointer guess whether it should delete its object or not. It you proceed that way, you will be caught at a time by a corner case or even if you managed to find all, by a new one created by an apparently unrelated change.

If you need to convert an `Image` to a `PtrImage` just say that you want to build a `shared_ptr<T>` from a T. There are 2 standard ways: a copy or a move, and in either the `shared_ptr` has ownership of its object.

In your example, as `Image` only returns a lvalue reference, you can only use a copy. You could have a move from a `VecImage` by taking ownership of its `data` member.